# Google sheets - How do I make a query that prints data from a dropdown box

Tags: google-sheets

I want to be able to pick a country from a dropdown box, which will then print the cities in the country as well as a string of numbers. Here is my google sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ypcJ72cE08f69djnaXE2urLIyk8o33E7oHoshDjkfCw/edit?usp=sharing

So for example, if I select India from my dropdown box, I want it to print:

Mumbai  646

New Delhi   264

Kolkata 346

But I want the cities and the numbers to be in different cells, just like how they are originally in C1:D4. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In A12 of the sheet you shared I entered

```
=offset(A1,1 ,match(A9,A1:H1,0)-1, counta(A1:A4),2)
```

See if that works for you?